# Set duration for jQuery function

Tags: jquery

I have looked high and low and can not find the solution. I would like to run a function consisting of animations for 5 seconds. I tried setInterval and setTimeout but could not get them to work properly. I have a function that creates blinking text and I want it to only run for a set time. Any help would be greatly appreciated. Here's my code

fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/kevinPHPkevin/5uUzE/140/

```
$.fn.blink = function () {
    $(this).animate({
       'opacity': '0.4'
    }, 200, function () {
        $(this).animate({
            'opacity': 1
        }, 200, function () {
            $(this).blink();
        });
    });
};

$('#highScore').blink();
```

Comment: So the problem is that you can't get it to stop? Kind of like the old `<blink>` tag?

Comment: You could recurse it and set a counter, then stop calling when the counter equals whatever number.

Comment: Thanks everyone for your input and help. All the solutions that have been provided are very good and perfectly useable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just set a counter:

```
var makeitstop = 0;
$.fn.blink = function () {
    $(this).animate({
        'opacity': '0.4'
    }, 200, function () {
        $(this).animate({
            'opacity': 1
        }, 200, function () {
            makeitstop++;
            if (makeitstop < 5) $(this).blink();
        });
    });
};
$('#highScore').blink();
```

**[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/5uUzE/142/)**

Comment: Thanks a lot. This works perfectly. I tried everything else but didn't think of a counter. To be honest I wasn't even aware a loop was taking place.

Comment: You're welcome. The loop part comes from calling `$(this).blink()`.

Answer (score 5):

a `setTimeout` and `stop(true,false)` will fix it.

```
$.fn.blink = function (duration) {
    var $self = $(this);
    setTimeout(function(){
        $self.stop(true,false).show();
    },duration || 10*1000);
    function blink () {
        $self.animate({
           'opacity': '0.4'
        }, 200, function () {
            $self.animate({
                'opacity': 1
            }, 200, function () {
                blink();
            });
        });
    }
    blink();
};
$("#oldschool").blink(30000); // blink for 30 seconds
```

http://jsfiddle.net/5uUzE/149/

Comment: I haven't tested this solution myself, but I like it much better than using some global variable that exists outside of the function to manage duration.

Comment: Thanks but this seems to repeat every 30 seconds, and never stop http://jsfiddle.net/kevinPHPkevin/5uUzE/146/

Comment: +1 but why don't you save `self` as a jQuery object instead of creating 1 everytime?

Answer (score 1):

Since you are creating a prototype function, i would sugest passing the number of call as an argument.

```
$.fn.blink = function (numCall) {
    var numCall = typeof numCall == 'number' ? numCall : 0
    if(numCall == 10) return false;
    $(this).animate({
       'opacity': '0.4'
    }, 200, function () {
        $(this).animate({
            'opacity': 1
        }, 200, function () {
            $(this).blink(++numCall);
        });
    });
};
```

Fiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/5uUzE/145/

As Kevin B pointed out, you can trasform this code to substract 1 tu numCall and that will allow you to set the number of time you want your element to blink.

Check his fiddle :  http://jsfiddle.net/5uUzE/150

Changes:

```
var numCall = typeof numCall == 'number' ? numCall : 10 //Default number of time if not set
if(numCall == 0) return false;
//Later
$(this).blink(--numCall);

//The call
$('div').blink(5);//blink 5 times
```

Comment: You could also make it actually blink x times based on what you pass to it: http://jsfiddle.net/5uUzE/150/

Comment: @KevinB Wow i didn't see it like that. Good move!

Comment: That's what I originally thought your solution did, then realized you were doing ++ rather than -- so i thought it would go on indefinitely,  I read right on past the `if(numCall == 10)`.

Answer (score 0):

```
var stop = false;
$.fn.blink = function () {
    if(stop)return false;
    $(this).animate({
        'opacity': '0.4'
    }, 200, function () {
        $(this).animate({
            'opacity': 1
        }, 200, function () {
           $(this).blink();
        });
    });
};

$('#highScore').blink();
setTimeout(function(){
  stop = true;
},5000)  // <-- Blink for 5 seconds
```

Demo `--->` http://jsfiddle.net/5uUzE/143/

Answer (score 0):

I created one using only CSS that should run smoother than any JavaScript solution.

```
<span id="highScore" class="animated flash">999</span>

    #highScore
```

{
    background: #c30000;
}

.animated {
    -webkit-animation-duration: 5s;
    -moz-animation-duration: 5s;
    -o-animation-duration: 5s;
    animation-duration: 5s;
    -webkit-animation-fill-mode: both;
    -moz-animation-fill-mode: both;
    -o-animation-fill-mode: both;
    animation-fill-mode: both;
}

@-webkit-keyframes flash {
    0%, 40%, 80% {
        opacity: .4;
    }
    20%, 60%, 100% {
        opacity: 1;
    }
}
@-moz-keyframes flash {
    0%, 40%, 80% {
        opacity: .4;
    }
    20%, 60%, 100% {
        opacity: 1;
    }
}
@-o-keyframes flash {
    0%, 40%, 80% {
        opacity: .4;
    }
    20%, 60%, 100% {
        opacity: 1;
    }
}
@keyframes flash {
    0%, 40%, 80% {
        opacity: .4;
    }
    20%, 60%, 100% {
        opacity: 1;
    }
}
.flash {
    -webkit-animation-name: flash;
    -moz-animation-name: flash;
    -o-animation-name: flash;
    animation-name: flash;
}

[jsFiddle to try it out](http://jsfiddle.net/docluv/tK8C9/2/)